# How to combine string inputs and generate array dynamically?

Tags: powershell

```
param([string]$roles,[string]$members)
```

Suppose I am passing input on the command line like this:

```
PS> role1,role2,role3,role4 member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4
```

The array I expect for this would be:

```
$array = @(
    @('role1', 'member1,member2'),
    @('role2', ''),
    @('role3', 'member3'),
    @('role4', 'member4')
)
```

I know to turn string to array:

```
$roles = 'role1,role2,role3,role4' -split ','
$members = 'member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4' -split ',,'
```

Now how do I combine `$roles` with `$members` so that each role will be associated with member(s)? and how wouldIi generate the array dynamically?

Pseudocode:

```
$array = @()

($roles+$members) | %{
    $role = $_.roles
    if ($_.members) {
        $_.members -split ',,' | ForEach-Object { $array += $role $_ }
    } else {
        $array += $role 
    }
}
```

**Note**: I am splitting members as an index of its own for each double comma because apparently semicolons aren't accepted on a command line because they break the command line, so I have to use double comma as delimiter.

**Note 2**: notice the 4 commas: ,,,, this indicates that role2 does not have members to add, so in essence it means between the 4 commas is no input for member to that index/item (role2), i.e. `,,EMPTY,,`.

Comment: embedded-in a-string semicolons will work. it's only the ones that are NOT in strings that are seen as command delimiters. ///// is there a reason you don't use something like `-RoleMember 'Role_A;Person_1,Person_2', 'Role_B;Person_2', 'Role_4;Person_1,Person_5'`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey TBH, the script is too complicated to change. i wouldnt know how to parse an input like that. i can make one common variable called $RoleMember per your suggestion, but then to minimize the amount of changes required for my script, i'd need to set each of the $CUBE_ROLE and $CUBE_MEMBER variables to the parsed $RoleMember combined input, which i wouldnt mind if thats not gonna require much changes to my existing script.

Comment: I would recommend using hashtables instead of arrays with two members.

Comment: @Cataster - if your script is that complex ... then you likely need to break it into functions internally that  handle _the strongly recommended minimum_ in each. one func for one narrow thing. then rework your script. ///// if that is not doable, then you need to write a pre-processor script that gathers the info, formats it as needed, and then submits it to the "too big to change" script. ///// however, any time a script is "too big to change" or "too complex to change" ... you almost certainly need to rewrite it.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey ive written it last year when i was new to powershell, and just kept adding onto it. only now when our team received TFS capability, i realized its not feasible to force the user to create a release everytime they want to add a bulk amount of members. but then the problem is i have higher priority tasks to take care of so i cant spend too much time on this script, let alone redesigning it. ill have to basically patch it here and there to get what i need for now, but might come back to it in the future and redesign it in an efficient eay if i have some time :)

Comment: @Cataster - real life ... [*grin*] ///// still, you CAN write a pre-processor for it to handle complex inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to stick with this parameter format, you can create the desired output array as follows:

```
$roles = 'role1,role2,role3,role4' -split ','
$members = 'member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4' -split ',,'

$i = 0
$array = @(foreach ($role in $roles) {
  , ($role, $members[$i++])
})
```

Note that if you pass your arguments from PowerShell, you need to *quote* them, as PowerShell will otherwise parse them as an *array*.

And with quoting you're free to use `;` in lieu of `,,`, for instance, to separate the member groups.

A better way to represent the argument data for later processing is to create an array of *custom objects* rather than a nested array:

```
$roles = 'role1,role2,role3,role4' -split ','
$members = 'member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4' -split ',,'

$i = 0
$array = @(foreach ($role in $roles) {
   [pscustomobject] @{
     Role = $role
     Members = $members[$i++] -split ','
   }
})
```

Each object in `$array` now has a `.Role` and a `.Members` property, the latter containing the individual members as a an *array* of strings.

Alternatively, you could create a[n ordered] *hashtable* from the input, keyed by role name, but that is only necessary if you need to access roles by *name* or if you wanted to rule out duplicate roles having been specified.

---

Here's an alternative argument format that is easier to understand:

```
$rolesAndMembers = 'role1 = member1,member2 ; role2= ; role3=member3 ; role4=member4'

$array = @(foreach ($roleAndMembers in ($rolesAndMembers -replace ' ' -split ';')) {
  $role, $members = $roleAndMembers -split '='
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Role = $role
    Members = $members -split ','
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter format is rather bizarre, but here's one way:

```
$roles = 'role1,role2,role3,role4' -split ','
$members = 'member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4' -split ',,'

$result = @()
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++ ) {
  $result += ,@($roles[$i],$members[$i])
}
```

I would recommend redesigning the script to use standard PowerShell parameters (the engineering effort would be worth it, IMO).

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend using hashtables/dictionaries to pass these role mappings:

```
param(
    [System.Collections.IDictionary]$RoleMembers
)

# now we can access each mapping by role name:
$RoleMembers['role1'] # member1, member2

# or iterate over them like an array:
foreach($role in $RoleMembers.Keys){
    $RoleMembers[$role]
}
```

You could use one of the construct the input argument from your current input strings:

```
$roles = 'role1,role2,role3,role4' -split ','
$members = 'member1,member2,,,,member3,,member4' -split ','

$roleMembers = @{}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++) {
  # `Where Length -ne 0` to filter out empty strings
  $roleMembers[$roles[$i]] = $members[($i*2)..($i*2+1)] |Where Length -ne 0
}
```

Comment: Your definition for `$members` is inaccurate. OP really does mean `-split ',,'`. It would be better if they had used `;` for the delimiter, like so: `$members = 'member1,member2;;member3;member4' -split ';'`.

Comment: @BaconBits i thought at first i wanst able to use ; so i stuck with the alternative double commas. but Lee_Dailey explained if i quote them i can use semicolon, which i am fine with.

Comment: so even with or without semicolon, i am getting this incorrect output (trying the construct solution): 
role1                          member1,member2
role3
role4
role2                          {member3, member4}

Comment: @Cataster note that the hashtable doesn't retain the order, try: `$roleMembers.GetEnumerator() |sort Name`

Comment: thanks, that does take care of the ordering issue, the output is still incorrect though. role2 is getting values  {member3, member4}, and role3 and role4 are empty. the correct output would be: role1 has member1, member2. role2 is empty. role3 has member3, and role4 has member4 in this example

Comment: @Cataster Are you sure you're running the code exactly as written in the answer?

Comment: yep. i opened a new powershell window, pasted the answer exactly as is.